# Align the table on the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I just want to put the table in the middle of the page. Any help would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Randy's first html web page !</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{background-image:url('Koala.gif');} 
h1
{
text-align:center;
}
h2
{
text-align:center;
}
p
{
text-align:center;
font-size:200%;
color:#00fff0;
}
div
{
background-color:#efffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<h1> Hello Professor</h1>
<h2> By: Randy White</h2>
<P> I haven't done anything like this before.</P> 
<P>Seems to be ok</P>
<P><img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" width="150" height="100" alt="Hydrangeas.jpg"></P> 
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>December</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2010</td>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try:

```
table {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

or:

```
table {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

BTW, this sets this for all tables. You might want to have the properties on a more specific selector (like `table.someclass`).

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. Maybe I am putting it in the incorrect place. Can you tell me where this would go.

Comment: Small mistake by me, I wanted it too short ;) Try now, works.

Answer (score 5):

old style is align="center":

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
```

Answer (score 2):

To horizontally align table in the middle of the page, and also make table width fit itself automatically, try below:

```
table {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```